# Odd and even on tr not working

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/v2tgjLjv/

anything wrong with this selector?

```
tr:odd {
  background: green;
}

tr:even {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The question is pretty clear and I'm sure it helped quite a lot of people, including me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use nth-child:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

`:odd` and `:even` are jQuery pseudo element selector not of css.

Answer (score 1):

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background: red}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: green}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="d0">
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="d1">
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="d1">
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="d1">
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: green;
 }
 
 tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: lightgreen;
 }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Use all the tags `<table>` and `<td>`. Also use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` instead of `:odd` and `:even` 
Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v2tgjLjv/9/